# Why do I get a PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]

Tags: sql, doctrine

I'm trying to make a prepared SQL statement using Doctrine.
If I hard code the value in the SQL query it's working:

```
public function search()
{

    $sql        = 'SELECT `name` FROM `files` WHERE `name` = "myfile.exe"';
    $query      = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $status     = $query->execute();
    $searchResult    = $query->fetchAll();
    $searchResult    = array(
                  'service' => $searchResult,
                  'status'  => $status
                  );
    $searchResult    = $this->conn->fetchAll($sql);


    return $searchResult;
}
```

But if I try to pass the value with a parameter it doesn't and give my the **PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]**

```
public function search()
{

    $sql        = 'SELECT `name` FROM `files` WHERE `name` = :service';
    $query      = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindValue(":service", "myfile.exe");
    $status     = $query->execute();
    $searchResult    = $query->fetchAll();
    $searchResult    = array(
                  'service' => $searchResult,
                  'status'  => $status
                  );
    $searchResult    = $this->conn->fetchAll($sql);


    return $searchResult;
}
```

I can't figured out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried running the sql statement directly from a MySQL command line to see if that works? Also, is this just pure Doctrine code, or are you using a PHP framework like Laravel or Symfony?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days stuck on this problem I finally find the solution.
I just remove the line:

```
 $searchResult    = $this->conn->fetchAll($sql);
```

So the code below is working fine:

```
public function search($service)
{

    $sql        = 'SELECT `name` FROM `files` WHERE `name` = ":service"';
    $query      = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindValue(":service", $service);
    $status     = $query->execute();
    $searchResult    = $query->fetchAll();
    $searchResult    = array(
                  'service' => $searchResult,
                  'status'  => $status
                  );


    return $searchResult;
}
```

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html

It should be:

```
public function search(){
    $sql        = 'SELECT `name` FROM `files` WHERE `name` = ?';
    $query      = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindValue(1, "myfile.exe");
    $status     = $query->execute();
    $searchResult    = $query->fetchAll();
    $searchResult    = array(
              'service' => $searchResult,
              'status'  => $status
              );
    $searchResult    = $this->conn->fetchAll($sql);

    return $searchResult;
}
```

Comment: I got the same error "PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1". And I need to use named parameter.

Comment: Well to be honest i don't see anything else that could be it i thought maybe using the positional instead of the named prepared statements like could change something but obviously not. what you did should also have worked. Are you sure you didn't accidentally removed/change anything else when adding it maybe a column name?

Answer (score 0):

Ah - I see it now, it the quotes around the file name.
Try this (might work):

```
$query->bindValue(':service', '"myfile.exe"');
```

Answer (score -2):

Could it be that you're losing a set of quotes while passing the file name? I don't do much PHP. I'd comment but my rep is too low.

Does this work?

```
public function search()
{

    $sql        = 'SELECT `name` FROM `files` WHERE `name` = ":service"';
    $query      = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindValue(":service", "myfile.exe");
    $status     = $query->execute();
    $searchResult    = $query->fetchAll();
    $searchResult    = array(
                  'service' => $searchResult,
                  'status'  => $status
                  );
    $searchResult    = $this->conn->fetchAll($sql);


    return $searchResult;
}
```

Comment: Do not put quotes around binded placeholders.